# How to construct an object to be merged with $$ROOT in mongoDB in SpringBoot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot to operate mongoDB. The problem I am meeting with is as follows:
When use the $mergeObjects operator, I want to merge two objects ranging from a artificial object  to the $$ROOT, i.e., the following code segment. I wonder how to code the user-defined object in SpringBoot?

```
$mergeObjects: [
        {
            "propertyA":"$xx.xx",
            "propertyB":"$xxx.xxx",
            "propertyC":"$xxxx.xxxx"
        }, "$$ROOT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. It's easy. A hashMap could help.